# Rounding to 5 cents - better approach

Tags: javascript, algorithm, rounding

The total price should be rounded to 5 cents according to following rules.

1. If number ends with 0.01 to 0.04 cents, round number down, e.g. 15.52 to 15.50
2. If number ends with 0.06 to 0.09 cents, round up, e.g. 15.57 to 15.60
3. If number is less than 5 cents then number price is 5 cents, e.g. 0.04 to 0.05
4. If number ends with 0 or 5 cents then don't round.

I have come up with following approach but seems to heavy and wonder if someone has a better idea?

```
var divisionValue = 0.05;

if (number > 0 && number < divisionValue) {
    return divisionValue;
}

var roundedNumber = number;

var division = roundedNumber / divisionValue;
var divisionFormatted = +(division).toFixed(2);

var moduloRemainder = divisionFormatted % 1;
var divisionRemainderFormatted = +(moduloRemainder).toFixed(2);

// When there is no remainder, the value ends with 0.05 or 0.1
if (divisionRemainderFormatted === 0) {
    return roundedNumber;
} else if (divisionRemainderFormatted !== 0) {
    var diff = divisionFormatted - divisionRemainderFormatted;
    if (diff % 2) {
        // For values ending with 0.06 to 0.09 round up
        roundedNumber = Math.ceil(number * 10) / 10;
    } else {
        // For values ending with 0.01 to 0.04 round up
        roundedNumber = Math.floor(number * 10) / 10;
    }
}

return +(roundedNumber).toFixed(2
```

Test

```
it('Slovak rounding to 5 eurocents', function () {
    // not round
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(23)).toBe(23);
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(23.1)).toBe(23.10);
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(23.15)).toBe(23.15);

    // round down
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(23.11)).toBe(23.10);
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(23.12)).toBe(23.10);
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(23.13)).toBe(23.10);
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(23.14)).toBe(23.10);

    // round up
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(23.17)).toBe(23.20);
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(23.18)).toBe(23.20);
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(23.19)).toBe(23.20);

    // round to 0.05
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(0.01)).toBe(0.05);
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(0.02)).toBe(0.05);
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(0.03)).toBe(0.05);
    expect(MathService.roundToFiveEurocent(0.04)).toBe(0.05);
});
```

Comment: Your rules for rounding (in Slovakia) are incorrect. E.g. 3.66 should be 3.65, not 3.70 and 15.57 should be 15.55.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to play with adding 0.05 and defining your exceptions

```js
// not round
values = [
  [23, 23],
  [23.1, 23.10],
  [23.15, 23.15],

  // round down
  [23.11, 23.10],
  [23.12, 23.10],
  [23.13, 23.10],
  [23.14, 23.10],

  // round up
  [23.17, 23.20],
  [23.18, 23.20],
  [23.19, 23.20],

  // round to 0.05
  [0.01, 0.05],
  [0.02, 0.05],
  [0.03, 0.05],
  [0.04, 0.05]
]

function test_round(val) {
  to_round = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2)
  if (to_round < 0.05)
    return 0.05

  ref = to_round * 10
  if (ref - parseInt(ref) == 0.5)
    return to_round

  temp = parseFloat(to_round) + 0.05;
  clean = parseFloat(parseInt(temp * 10) / 10)
  return clean
}

function test(_vals) {
  for (v of _vals) {
    if (v[1] != test_round(v[0])) {
      console.log(['Failed rounding', '-', v, '-', test_round(v[0])].join(' '))
    }
  }
}

test(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner...

```js
function rt5( x ) {return x < 0 ? null : 0 < x && x < 0.05 ? 0.05 : x * 20 % 1 === 0 ? x : Math.floor( ( x + 0.05 ) / 0.1 ) * 2 / 20 }

console.log( `rt5( 0.02 ) = ${rt5(0.02)}` ); 
console.log( `rt5( 0.14 ) = ${rt5(0.14)}` ); 
console.log( `rt5( 0.15 ) = ${rt5(0.15)}` ); 
console.log( `rt5( 0.16 ) = ${rt5(0.16)}` );

console.log( `rt5( 999999999999.94 ) = ${rt5(999999999999.94)}` );
console.log( `rt5( 999999999999.95 ) = ${rt5(999999999999.95)}` );
console.log( `rt5( 999999999999.96 ) = ${rt5(999999999999.96)}` );

console.log( `rt5( -1.05 ) = ${rt5(-1.05)}` );
```